# declaration error identifier not found or not unique

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-debugging

```
 pragma solidity 0.7.4;

 contract MyToken {
    address public minter;

    mapping (address => uint) public balances;
    
    constructor(){
        minter = msg.sender;
    }
    
    function mint(address receiver, unit amount) public {
        require(msg.sender == minter);
        balances[receiver] += amount;
    }
}
```

oKAY this should be a simple piece of code that works that I watched from this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1kMUPj5cP-0
as I'm learning how to deploy contracts (c# and c++ background) Its not making sense how this simple code isn't working. Please help me understand

I get the error
"TestContract2.sol:12:37: DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique. function mint (address receiver, unit amount) public {
^--^
"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit cryptic, but there's a typo in your function parameters - `unit` -> `uint`:

Change:

```
function mint(address receiver, unit amount) public {
```

To:

```
function mint(address receiver, uint amount) public {
```